# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'allWpPage')

Tags: wordpress, graphql, gatsby, headless-cms

I am a beginner at Gatsby. Recently start to build a headless website with WordPress & Gatsby. I want to create dynamic pages & post via gatsby-node.js.
When querying into http://localhost:8000/___graphql then shows query result. How can I fix the issue?

gatsby-node.js 
code link: https://codeshare.io/8pz3qJ
[image]

Comment: How's your `gatsby-config.js` file?

Comment: Here is gatsby-config.js.
https://codeshare.io/PdAbzE

Answer (score 0):

The issue here, besides your `gatsby-node.js` looks good and the pages should be created correctly, is that you don't have a connection to your WordPress site and the code breaks at:

```
_.each(result.data.allWpPage.edges, edge => {
```

Because `allWpPage` is `undefined`.

In addition, your promise rejection is not doing what it should (because it's not throwing any exception:

```
if (result.errors) {
  console.log(result.errors)
  reject(result.errors)
}
```

Should be something like:

```
if (!result) {
  console.log(result.errors)
  reject(result.errors)
}
```

The issue is:

```
{
    resolve: 'gatsby-source-wordpress',
    options: {
      "url": "http://learn.test/graphql"
    }
```

This URL doesn't seem to be providing any valid GraphQL schema.

I'd recommend following one of the [`gatsby-plugin-wordpress` tutorials](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/tutorials/index.md) or diving directly on one of the [starters](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/blob/master/packages/gatsby-source-wordpress/docs/tutorials/creating-a-new-site-from-a-starter.md) which has a minimum default configuration:

```
  resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
  options: {
    url: `https://wpgatsbydemo.wpengine.com/graphql`,
  },
```

Here's one of the starters with a valid and running WordPress GraphQL configuration: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/starters/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-wordpress-blog